# Inserting struct element to a struct array alphabetically?

Tags: c

I need help on a function that I'm confused on. I need to iterate through the struct array to find out which index that I need to insert a new element. The struct array consists of firstname, lastname, grade level, and grade. I need to insert them alphabetically by last name. If there is another last name that is the same, I need to insert it alphabetically by first name instead. I think I have the right idea so far, but I'm really confused on how to insert the new element into the right index, and then move all the other elements in my struct array over. Here's the code I have for the function so far,

```
void add(char* student_firstname, char* student_lastname, char* student_grade, char* student_level, struct student* list)
{
if(count > 30){
    printf("No more room left in the array!");
}
else{

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(strcmp(list[i].lastName, student_lastname) == 0){
            // There is another last name in the list
            // Must sort alphabetically by first name
            // Sorts by first name then returns 0 and adds one to count
        }


    } // end for loop to determine if same last name is in array


    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

        if(strcmp(student_lastname, list[i].lastName) < 0){
            // Need to insert in index i - 1
            int index = i - 1;
        }

    }

}

}
```

The count variable is the size of my struct list. Could someone show me by code how to insert a new element alphabetically by last name? It would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Also, 30 is the max size of the struct array.

EDITED VERSION:

```
void add(char* student_firstname, char* student_lastname, char* student_grade, char* student_level, struct student* list)
{
if(count > 30){
    printf("No more room left in the array!");
}
else{

    int i = 0;
    while( i < count && compare_student( list[i], new_student ) > 0 ){
        i++;

        // Move everything over 1 and insert

    }

}

}
```

Comment: IMHO you haven't reached the point of asking how to insert the element as you have not produced code to find the right index to insert into. Perhaps you should do that first? To insert something into an array you have to make space for it by copying everything starting from the insertion point down (or up depending on your point of view) one position.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the first thing your `add` function does is to make a `student` record with the data provided.  Create a function to compare two `student` records:

```
int compare_student( struct student *a, struct student *b )
{
    int cmp = strcmp( a->lastName, b->lastName );
    if( cmp == 0 ) cmp = strcmp( a->firstName, b->firstName );
    return cmp;
}
```

Now it's much easier to look through your list for the spot to insert:

```
int i = 0;
while( i < count && compare_student( &list[i], &new_student ) > 0 ) i++;
```

Once you have that, you just shuffle everything between `i` and `count` one place to the right, and drop the new record in.  Will leave that exercise to you.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code in my post. So that would find the index I need to insert it into? Now I just need to actually insert it?

Comment: Also, the 'new_student' parameter is undeclared?

Comment: My answer assumes you can read between the lines.  It's not copy-and-paste solution.  The nature of your question is that you need some help with a homework assignment.  So I'm not just going to write it for you.  Now, read my answer again, and think for yourself what `new_student` actually is.  Then, read my description of how to insert, and write the loop.  I'm sure you can do it.

Comment: I don't want you to give me the copy and paste solution! I agree I need to learn this myself. I'm just confused as to what new_student is. The parameters that go into the function are firstname, lastname, etc. Do I need to add new_student as a parameter for the function?

Comment: No.  Read the first sentence in my answer. =P

Answer (score 0):

Start at the end of the array and work backwards.  For each element you examine, if it comes after the one you're adding, copy it to the next higher position in the array.  Keep going until you either reach the beginning of the array or encounter an element that belongs before the one you're adding.  Then add the new element.